# is inumber Primary Number or not with forloop . n/2 . confusion

Tags: c++, for-loop

in example below code tells you if number is Primary or not in a for loop . i understand most of it but one thing confuses me . why , first: when i check if 2 is Prmary number or not progrmamme tells you that it is Prmary number which is correct but i don't understand why when it is checked against i -2 , first iteration  it tells  you that it is . what in a code decides that it is Primary number ? we know that 2%2 leaves no remainder. code still tell you it is a Primary number.

2nd and even more confusing , when i checking if 9  is Prmary number , code says it is not a Primary number which is correct but in essence code should tell you that it is Primary number immediately after 9  is checked against i-2 . 9%2 leaves a remainder and " break " should stop the loop without checking it with next iteration i=3 which is when it is correctly decided that it is not aPrimary number .  9%3 leaves no remainder and it is not a Primary number . what in this programme decides that it shold be checked against i-3 ?

Thanks.

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    
    int i, n;
    bool is_prime = true;
    
    cout << "Enter a positive integer: ";
    cin >> n;
    
  
    if (n == 0 || n == 1) {
        is_prime = false;
    }
    
    
    for (i = 2; i <= n/2; ++i) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            is_prime = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if (is_prime){
        cout << n << " is a prime number" << " checked against : " << i << endl;
        cout << endl;
    }
    else
        cout << n << " is not a prime number"<< " checked against : " << i << endl;
    cout << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `n == 2` is the loop even entered? For 9 you say it should fail when `i == 2` because of the remainder, but the condition is checking for no remainder so the loop iterates again and checks with `i == 3`. You should consider running this code in a debugger so you can watch how it executes since you seem to be a little confused by how it works.

Comment: Off topic for the question but interesting: Note that you can optimise this as mathematically you only have to iterate up to √n. So your bound can be `i*i <= n`

Comment: Since all primes except for 2, are odd, you can test with 2, then the loop should start at 3 and increment by 2.  This will reduce your trials by half.

Comment: Your question title talks about `inumber`.  Where is this symbol?  I didn't find it in the code.

Comment: You should put the `for` loop into an `else` clause.  If `n` is zero or one, you still try to run the `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you are not understanding the loop.
`for (i = 2; i <= n/2; ++i)` says that you start with a value of 2, and as long as `i` is less than half of `n`, execute the loop.

When `n=2`, the value of `i` is never less than `n/2` (1) so it does not execute the loop at all.

When `n=9`, the value if `i` can range from 2 to 4 (integer division rounds down). So it will check those values, dropping out when it hits 3.

The `break` statement in the loop is only triggered when there is no remainder, so `(9 % 2)` will not execute that code.

Answer (score 0):

I spent almost a month figuring it out . it makes sence now . with 2 i missed the fact that 2 is the only even namber that has 2 only factors. that's what i was confused mainly not because the way for loop in given code works . confusion about why 9 and some other numbers are not reported as  the Prime number when it is checked against first iteration i= 2 was that number (lets say 9) has to go though all the iterations defined by n/2 untill it hits i(numer)that divides it without remainder and only then loop is stoped  " by "brak;" i=3 in case of 9 .

Thanks . i'm very new to coding had no prior experience so it takes little time untill i get my head around basics of coding